# burning an iso using the built in windows7 burner, only desktop.ini on the cd?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, burning, iso-image

I am trying to burn an iso using the built-in Windows 7 burner. After it burns (with verifying turned on) all the disc has on when viewing the directory is a `desktop.ini` file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To burn image Files in windows 7 you don't go to explorer and use the Burn menu.

Instead, you right-click the iso file you wish to burn and select `Open With -> Windows Disk Image Burner` from the dropdown menu.